# Is there a way to rename output abreviated columns in a CTE query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join, common-table-expression

I need to rename the output columns of a CTE query. I guess it could be done with the command `AS` but I don't know where to place it.

For example

```
with
   table1 as (
   select 
      atribute1 as a1
      atribute2 as a2
   from table2 
   ),         
   table3
   select
      atribute3 as a3 
   from table4
)
select
   table1.a1
   table1.a2
   table3.a3
   from table1
   join table 3 on table3.a3=table1.a1
;
```

This will give me an output of a table with column names like `a1` (first column), `a2` (second column), `a3` (third column). I want to rename them as `a1`, `a2` and `a3`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want to alias the columns in the final resultset. You can do:

```
with 
    table1 as (...),
    table3 as (...)
select
    t1.a1 as first_column
    t1.a2 as second_column
    t3.a3 as third_column
from table1 t1
join table3 t3 on t3.a3 = t1.a1
```